# Angular form submission with ng-submit not getting called

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do a simple submission using angular, however the $scope.account_create.submit function never gets called on submission, I added the name attribute to the form, made sure that the submit button lies within the form tag, but still no luck

**Controller**

```
var tapp = angular.module('tailorapp.controllers').controller(
  'AccountCtrl', 
  ['$scope', '$state' , '$stateParams', '$ionicLoading', '$resource', 'localStorageService', 'settings', 'api', 'notification',
  function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $ionicLoading,  $resource, localStorageService, settings, api, notification) {

    var _returnPath = $stateParams.returnPath;
    $scope.mode = "signup";
    $scope.account_create = {};

    $scope.showSignIn = function(){
      $scope.mode = "signin";
    };
    $scope.showSignUp = function(){
      $scope.mode = "signup";
    };   

   $scope.account_create.submit = function(item, event) {
        _create_account($scope.account_create).success(function(data){
          $state.go( _returnPath );
        });
    };
```

**Html**

```
<ion-view title="Account">

<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-bag righthd-icon" ng-click="gotoCart();"></button>
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-person righthd-icon"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>

<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>

<ion-content class="has-header">

    <div ng-show="mode == 'signup'">
        <form name="account_create"  ng-submit="account_create.submit()">
            <div class="card">
...
                <div class="item item-divider">
                    <button class="button button-positive" type="submit">Create Account</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form name is also account_create. So angular replaces your own acount_create object containing the submit function with the NgFormController instance backing the form directive.

Answer (score 5):

i found that the ng-submit is not called when ng-controller is not called directly on the form element or element called directly before form element. I was really mad having to find out such rules after 8 hours of trying to figure out why nothing happens in ng-submit.

Comment: This is a really important bit that suspected but I haven't found mentioned anywhere else.

Comment: i have the same problem here i was searching for the bug for hours until i found that 
, thanks 
but i don't understand why

Answer (score 2):

When you add the attribute `name` to a form, you are creating a varibale in the $scope with that name. In your code, by adding `name="account_create"` you are overwriting your `$scope.account_create` defined in the controller.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

If you rename the form it should work.

Comment: which variable name? account_create? just tried it and same old

Comment: I didn't notice that you were naming your form, please see my edit